# Basic Requirements for accessing Gmail with Oauth2 3 legged

Tags: java, gmail, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-java-client

What are the basic requirements (library) to access gmail using Oauth2 3 legged?

Is there any java library supported for this access?

Any kickstart example using java?

I found [the example](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/wiki/JavaSampleCode) from google, but it seem like using python script to get access token. And I am getting confused.

Any inputs will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two high level steps to access the Gmail APIs using OAuth2:

1. Obtain a user access token. To accomplish this, read [this guide](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) first, it contains the basic steps. Then, checkout the Google OAuth2 Java [client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/), which has convenience classes that abstract away some of the low level protocol details.
2. Use the token to authenticate w/ Gmail IMAP/SMTP and start reading mails! You already found out the relevant library in your link included in the question.

Answer (score -3):

Use the token to authenticate w/ Gmail IMAP/SMTP and start reading mails! You already found out the relevant library in your link included in the question.

Comment: Did you just copy and paste vlatko's answer by mistake?